# xslt filtering for dataform web part paging stays in sharepoint

Tags: xml, xslt, sharepoint, filter

i have a dataformwebpart and i used following code for xslt filtering on it.

```
 [contains(translate(@Title,'ABCÇDEFGĞHIİJKLMNOÖPQRSTUÜVWXYZ','abcçdefgğhıijklmnoöpqrstuüvwxyz'),translate($userName,'ABCÇDEFGĞHIİJKLMNOÖPQRSTUÜVWXYZ','abcçdefgğhıijklmnoöpqrstuüvwxyz'))or(string-length($userName)=0)]
```

so far everything is good. i sent a querystring named as userName to the page, and dataformwebpart filters the users.

by the way dataform web part has a paging limited with 30 items.

the 31. item (personel 42)

when i search as 42; no result. but when i click the second page button. it shows what i want.

(in picture[image])

so what should i do for getting result in first page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working on it for days the solution i found is

xslt filtering works after paging mechanism works. thats why in second page i found what i want.

i cancelled the paging options of the dataformwebpart. then i wrote my paging by using jquery,